# service in c# to connect to sql ,

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database, and I need to write in c# a script to execute some statements and save the result of these statements to another database, and each statement has a condition like run daily or weekly.
Then I need to save this script like a service in the window server to run it automatically.
so 1 service, for many statements, and each statement has condition inside the service.

any suggestions, or examples for this scenario?
thank you

Comment: kindly explain your question in steps.What is your first step and what do you want from 1st step then next step

Comment: What is your question? How to create a Windows Service? Or how to run code at certain intervals? Both have been asked and answered before. Read [ask] and try searching.

Comment: @CodeCaster , I am sorry, I think you did not understand what I mean.
first, I need to write a script to run statements from old data base and save the result to new data has , with some condition to execute , so how I can write this code with certain intervals , I hope now the question is clear

Comment: @ZoraizHammad
thank you :) 
first: I need to write a script in c#  to execute  SQL statements with a condition (daily or weekly ). 
second, convert it to  a service will be run automatically,
I am now at step number 1

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

1. Write your code in a console application and convert it to a windows server. If you write the code perfectly and create some timer or or function to handle the jobs they whould be run exactly at the desired time. [Manual here](https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c)
2. Using windows task scheduler for each job and create a scheduler for them. For example if you have 3 jobs (hourly,daily and weekly) you can create three separated console application and create 3 scheduled jobs in windows task scheduler. Here you have a log of last execution time, the result, the erorr etc... [More info here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)

Comment: Shokran Mahmoud :)
for option 1, ya i know i need to conver it to service , but my problem now how I can write this code with some condition .
for option2 , ya in windows we can run this service  no problem about this till now :) , if you can help me and put any example about how to write this script with some condition , and thank you again.

Comment: @Doaa If your condition is time based follow the second solution and manual link I sent.
You only write your script as a console application without considering condition (daily or weekly). The task scheduler runs you console application daily or weekly.

Comment: for example now I need to write a script for 4 SQL statements  and each statement has a condition, so if I take option number 2 , I will generate 4 service .
eh saraha,  it is easier :),
3andak methal 3la write script c# to run SQL statement ?

Comment: yes @Doaa write you scripts in c# and create console application.

Comment: ok, do u have a good example about run sql statements between 2 databases in c#?